# bootstrap 4 container-fluid is not full width after removing the default padding

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a full width web page by Bootstrap 4.

I try to remove the original 15px padding of container-fluid, but it is still not working.

Details on jsfiddle. I marked the whole background as purple but u can see the jumbotron is not fully cover on the purple background.

```
<style>
        .container-fluid {
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
```

[jsddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ender/r4vnpday/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `p-0` and `m-0` utility classes on the **col** and **jumbotron** (no extra CSS needed)...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 p-0" style="background: purple;">
            <div class="jumbotron m-0">
                <h2>
                        Hello, world!
                    </h2>
                <p>
                    This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">Learn more</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/iAQiRARTFR

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
       your-content-goes-here
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#examples

Answer (score 1):

Adding the class `container-full-width` worked for me.

```
<div  class="container-full-width">
    <div  class=" row ">
        <div class="col-12">
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following to get rid of the purple space

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin: 0;
}
```

However, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50389225/4513747 provides a more elegant solution using the existing classes.